# Failed to launch exported rcp product in Eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I was able to launch my RCP product on Eclipse Neon and after exporting it as product I was not able to launch the product. In the log  It is showing and error

!ENTRY com.xxxx.phoenix.xxxx.xx_4.2.1 2 0 2017-07-25 11:49:39.864
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module:

then followed by a lot of dependency issues and finally ending up with

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-07-25 11:49:40.574
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sort out the dependency issues. If you are using an xxx.product file make sure it lists every plugin/feature that is required.

Comment: There are no dependency issues while clicking the validate plugin option.

Comment: There are no dependency issues while clicking the validate plugin option.Also all the dependency plugins are added in the product file.I am able to launch it from from eclipse.but  exported product it is not working.I am working on the linux machine.

Comment: Launching from within Eclipse uses the configuration in the 'Run Configurations' dialog, it does not look at the .product file.

Comment: I am launching the product from the product page and I am adding all the plugins required as dependencies in the dependencies page.This plugins will reflect in the product file as well ?.Or I need to add the dependencies separately to the product file ?

Comment: You must fill in the 'Contents' page in the .product file with every plugin/feature you want to be included in the exported product.

Comment: Yes,I am doing that.Then also I am getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support, we were able to resolve the issue. It is actually related to batik plugin.The batik plugin exported is 1.6 and the expected is 1.7 version.But in the contents file the version we selected is 1.7 only . We don't know hwy it is happening.Thank very much for your support.